# OAuth2 refresh token - how to refresh?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a program that automates some actions with my Gmail account (using Ruby). I generate a callback URL and go to it, which gives me an auth code. Then, I request a refresh token using the auth code.

Now, after the refresh token expires, I was under the impression I can just grab another refresh token using the original auth code. But it seems I keep having to get a new auth code - which is frustrating because I'm hard coding the auth code in my script right now. Is this normal? Am I misunderstanding refresh tokens?

Answer (score 0):

consider code as one-time-password to get a access_token. With access_token you are also getting refresh_token, both have expiration date set - refresh_token is valid for longer time, but if it expires you have to begin whole flow from the very beginning ( getting code )

Comment: Interesting. So how come I'm able to use people's apps that use OAuth with Gmail and it doesn't have to reauthenticate every time? Are they doing it behind the scenes? I tried getting an auth code from the callback URL using curl but I haven't been able to grab the redirect URL to extract the code...